# label left align

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html layout here ([in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLJgH/10/)):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label class="name">Name1:</label>
        <label class="value">value1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="name">Name22222:</label>
        <label class="value">value22222</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to left align the names & values, so I did the following CSS:

```
.name{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.value{
    text-align:left;
}
```

But they are not left aligned, where am I wrong?

**---update--**

I mean `value1` and `value22222` **left align** while `name1` and `name2222` left algin. You can see from my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLJgH/10/) link that `value1` and `value22222` are not at the same left align level currently. I need it like this:

```
Name1:        value1
Name22222:    value22222
```

Comment: text is by default left align :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything looks left aligned to me.

Do you, by chance mean you want everything on one line?

```
.name{
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
float: left;
}

.value{
text-align:left;
float:left;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WLJgH/11/)

Based on your edit to the question.... the only way to accomplish that is to have a width for the .name class. Without a set width, .value will alway fall immediately to the left of .name and vertically, they will not align to the left.

```
.name{
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;
width:100px;}
```

Of course, setting a width for the .name label present a problem since it's assumed the .name content will be different lengths. You could set a width then add a text overflow option to prevent layout breaking.....

```
.name{
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;
width:50px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;}
```

Answer (score -1):

do this

```
.name{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
    float:left;
}

.value{
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: People have got to stop *mindlessly* suggesting `!important` as a solution for everything. It doesn't work that way.